# How to fix "ID longer than 32 characters" error when upgrading?

Tags: 8, migrations

Why am I getting the following error when I try to upgrade my site from Drupal 7 to 8 using the [Migrate Upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade) module? After a progress of 11% my site's throwing an Ajax error:

> An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
>
> Debugging information follows.
>
> Path:
>   /mysite/?q=en/file/ajax/field_slideshow_image/und/form-ESe-qn-oh9D4OVpLClBz2wTv1mHUxaTWHmj2hi5V3aw
>
> StatusText: n/a
>
> ResponseText: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server
>   error has occurred.
>
> ReadyState: undefined

The actual error message is the following:

> Source ID comment_node_industry_recognition: Attempt to create a
>   bundle with an ID longer than 32 characters:
>   comment_node_industry_recognition().
>   (/media/public_html/public_html/drupal/drupalmigrationfinal/‌​core/lib/Drupal/Core‌​/Entity/Entity.php:4‌​08)

Comment: Report a bug in the core issue queue. This will need to be fixed there.

Comment: This bug should be filed in the core issue queue.

Comment: There actually already is an issue for this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2565931